# pull records from postgresql after last record retrieved

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, jquery

I'm making a query that pulls a lot of data from a sql table. I'd like to implement an infinite scroll feature so that only 25 records or so are pulled at a time.

I'm having some trouble though.

This query gets called when a user scrolls down. jquery posts to php the last id of the last record that was put on the page;

```
//ie, this js pulls the id 
var last_order_number = $('.order_number_divs:last').attr('id');

//from this div
<div id="2476" class="order_number_divs">   1121310  </div>
```

I thought that if I selected two more results where the id was greater than the previous id on the page, I would definitely get the following two results. However, I get the same two results every time.

```
SELECT 
    id,
    order_number
    FROM sales_orders
    WHERE id > '$last_id'
    ORDER BY id ASC
    LIMIT 2
```

This is the jquery that runs the data through the template to populate the div. Since [vkTemplate](http://www.eslinstructor.net/vktemplate/) does not support appending, once it is done populating the div with the content, I remove the id of the just-populated div, and give the id to the div below it, so the next time there is a scroll, the content will go in that div.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 10) {



        var last_order_number = $('.order_number_divs:last').attr('id');

        console.log(last_order_number);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            url: "queries/privileged_search_more_content.php",
            data: "user=" + "<?=$_COOKIE['username']?>" + "&last_order_number=" + last_order_number,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                $('#INT-order_information_container').vkTemplate("templates/get_orders_initial_template.tmpl?" + <?=time()?> , data, function () {

                $('#INT-order_information_container').removeAttr('id');
                $('#template_div_next').removeAttr('id')
                                       .attr('id', 'INT-order_information_container');

                });
                console.log($.active);
            }
        });

    }
    });
```

Have you any ideas why the same two records are being pulled over and over?

Thanks much!

Also this scroll function I found seems to get invoked on up *and* down. But that's a different question. Just saying so you know that I'm aware of at least that much.

Comment: The query looks reasonable. What happens if you run it from psql, hand-substituting the last ID each time? If it works in psql, you can reasonably conclude that the problem is your code; you're probably not actually using the new rows, so you keep resubmitting the old ones. The query log could also be useful; enable `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` and restart Pg.

Comment: @CraigRinger I think that sounds really logical. Unfortunately, the postgre conf modifications will have to wait until the server guys are back in the office. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: If you can't modify `postgresql.conf` you can set it per-session in your database connection code using `SET log_statement ='all';` . Only statements from that connection will be logged to the PostgreSQL server logs. Also, I'm surprised you aren't working on a local PostgreSQL install for development/testing so you can set fast-but-unsafe options and so you don't need to worry about "the server guys".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vkTemplate does support appending. Take a look at the vkTemplate home page

http://www.eslinstructor.net/vktemplate/

There is menu item "**Append Technique**".

Another way to implement appending with vkTemplate is to customize this plugin. It's simple: open code and find lines #94,102,117    https://github.com/vkiryukhin/vkTemplate/blob/master/vktemplate.js

```
$(elm).empty().append(. . .)
```

and remove empty() from this expression.

Hope this helps,

-Vadim